# Android Studio SDK Manager won't open

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to open the SDK Manager in Android Studio, but everytime I get an error. The first time I open it, I see a progression bar which completes. But nothing opens. If I try again I get this error message:

```
Cannot launch SDK manager.
Output:

'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: SWT folder 'lib\x86_64' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

There are other topics on Stackoverflow with the same question. From those topics I discovered that maybe my Path environment variable is causing the error. I tried multiple things, but the error is still there..

My Systemvariables Path is:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\
```

Edit: The problem is fixed. I reinstalled Android Studio multiple times and somehow it worked.

Comment: find the directory you installed android studio then goto sdk=>tools and then click on the **android.bat** file. if you didnt find this file or if this didnt work please try reinstalling the sdk and then goto android studio and change your sdk path. If you want to learn more about getting started with android studio, check out [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/tools/android-studio/getting-started-with-android-studio.html) tutorial i made :D

Comment: May be it comes from the version of your O/S check it out